# Change the font in math mode in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm attempting to modify a beamer template for my own use. The theme uses the palatino font for the default text, but this extends to making everything, including the fonts in math mode, palatino. I'd like the math mode text to be in the default Computer Modern font. I'm pretty new to beamer, but I can't find anything in the manual for this specific case. I've attached the beamer font theme. What changes should I make (or can I make) to achieve the desired result?

```
% Maths
%\usefonttheme[stillsansserifmath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{serif}

% general font
%\renewcommand*\rmdefault{ppl} %Palatino
% monospaced

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt} % Latin Modern Mono Proportional Font

% Font sizes
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\Huge}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large, shape = \scshape}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\normalsize, shape = \normalshape}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{author in head/foot}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{quotation}{family=\sffamily}


\setbeamerfont*{bibliography entry author}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{bibliography entry title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont*{description item}{series=\bfseries}
```

Answer (score -3):

if you want can add profesional fonts at preamble

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

but if you are going to use videobeam the mathematical equations may not be visible